# Windows Phone Toolkit ListPicker background is White

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app. My app uses the ListPicker from the Toolkit. My app appears just fine. However, when I expand the ListPicker, the background is White. I can't read any of the items' text. When the ListPicker is collapsed, I can read the selected item's text just fine. Here is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                    
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="myGridTransform" />
  </Grid.RenderTransform>

  <Grid Background="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="app name" Margin="24,6,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
    <TextBlock Text="PAGE" Margin="24,0,0,6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
  </Grid>

  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,0,8,0">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Group" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" Margin="12,12,12,0" />
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="label" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
      <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="myListPicker" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,-6,12,-2" Background="Transparent" Loaded="myListPicker_Loaded">
        <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
          <toolkit:ListPickerItem Tag="1" Content="Option 1" />
          <toolkit:ListPickerItem Tag="2" Content="Option 2" />
        </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
      </toolkit:ListPicker>
      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="3" Margin="12,0,12,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="other details." VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may be caused by a bug of the toolkit.  It can be addressed by binding ItemsSource of the ListPicker to an ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

i think that is because your device or emulator under light theme

try updating the Expanded Visual State background

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the attribute Content, add the text of the ListPickerItem in the tag itself usinf . Like this:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="myListPicker">
    <sys:String>Option 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Option 2</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with `ListBox` where the background used to go black on increasing the height of `ListBox`. The problem lies with the parent container. Somehow `Grid`'s children don't abide by the background color when the context exceeds a particular height. Try replacing `Grid` with `StackPanel` as your parent container and set the background color of every child to your desired color. Should work.